# Can't create team project in team foundation server using VisualStudio 2013

Tags: visual-studio-2013

I try to create team project in team foundation server using VisualStudio 2013.

The problem that I can't see the **New Team Project** option  in menu.

[image]

or:

[image]

Any idea why I cant see it?

Answer (score 0):

Well, it's easy. The reason is you are **offline from TFS**. You can see there is a "local" behind your project playground.

You just need to connect to TFS first.(click connect to Team Projects→select a server→check projects→connect) Then everything is ok.